# Does adplus/cdb crash dumps still work on Vista 64 Ultimate?

Tags: vista64, crash-dumps, adplus, cdb

I am doing some research on a asp.net bug.  I tried to get adplus to give me a crash dump file from IIS crashing.  I have done this in the past on XP machines, but with my current Vista Ultimate setup - the adplus script doesn't spawn the 2nd window with CDB running.  I am running the adplus cmd window with admin priviledges.

Used Tess's setup instructions and all went ok.  But CDB is never spawned...

Has anyone managed to setup adplus/cdb crash dumps for IIS 7 in Vista 64 Ultimate? If so, can you explain how you did it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you get the 64 bit debugging package:
http://www.microsoft.com/whdc/devtools/debugging/install64bit.mspx#